# Javascript issues with show and hide

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a HTML form that I want to display inputs based on what has been selected in the initial options input.

The options is printed via PHP as it gets some of it's information from a PHP array.

```
<?php
        foreach ($type as $line_name => $line_id) {
                print "<option value='$line_id'>$line_name</option>";
        }
?>
```

So lets say for arguments sake, the options value will be printed as "123".

I then have the HTML of the field I want to hide. The php is just auto filling the data with something from the database.

```
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" size="30" maxlength="30" name="contact_firstname" id="first_name" value="<?php print $customer->cust_firstname; ?>"><br/></td></tr>
```

The Javascript I have is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#efm select[name="type"]').change(function () {
        if ($('#efm select[name="type"]').val() == '123') {
            $('#first_name').hide();
        } else if ($('#contact select[name="type"]').id() == 'EFM-2-PAIR'){
            $('#').show();
        } else if ($('#contact select[name="type"]').id() == 'EFM-4-PAIR'){

        } else {
            $('#').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

This currently isn't working, the field "first_name" is still on the screen when selecting "123" from the selection, I have a feeling it's because it's pulled in from the PHP so it's struggling to read it, but I am not an expert.

Any help here would be amazing

Comment: $('#') you don't select anything

Comment: I left those blank as I am just testing the first if, or would that be enough reason for it to completely fail? Once thing I need to mention the form name and id is "efm"

Comment: $('#efm select[name="type"]') are you sure of it, do you enter in the function  as expected ?

Comment: do you have any errors on console?

Comment: Are you sure your selector is good ? Make en alert or print something in console before the if condition. Maybe your "on change" listener is not working.

Comment: Are sure '123' is the option value? You state 'options value will be printed as 123'. Is the option text or value 123?

Comment: The actuall text printed is a string, just like the 2 other options in the javascript. I just changed the first option to make it easier on the eyes.

Comment: This appears on the console (Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function) on line 2, does the word document need to relate to a file name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#type').on('change', function(e) {
        alert($(this).val())
        if ($(this).val() == '190452') { // Bath Business Park Ethernet Rental
            $('#first_name').hide();
        } else if($(this).val() == '105561'){ //EFM-2-PAIR
            $('#surname').hide();
        } else if($(this).val() == '105581'){ //EFM-4-PAIR
            $('#company_name').hide();
        } else if($(this).val() == '105601'){ // EFM National Ethernet Rental
            $('#company_name').hide();
        }
    });
})
```

This was the code that fixed the issue, it's because the value type was actually an array holding 2 pieces of information it was having issues reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
$('#efm select[name="type"]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == '123') {
        $('#first_name').hide();
    }else
    if($('#contact select[name="type"]').attr('id') == 'EFM-2-PAIR'){
        // this won't work... $('#').show();
        // the hash tag is the begining of an id selector..
        // $('#some-id').show(); will work better!
    }else
    if ($('#contact select[name="type"]').attr('id') == 'EFM-4-PAIR'){

    } else {
        // won't work... $('#').hide();
    }
});
```

this is all assuming there is a select element with the name 'type' inside a containing element with the id of 'contact'.. actually not sure what you are trying to accomplish with those conditionals, maybe you meant to check the values?

```
 if($('#contact select[name="type"]').val() == 'EFM-4-PIAR') ...
```

otherwise unless you are dynamically changing the id's somewhere, they will always be true..

if you are just checking for other option values from the same select then use...

```
...
}else
if($(this).val() == 'EFM-2-PAIR'){
  //do something
}else
if($(this).val() == 'EFM-4-PAIR'){
  //do something else..
}else{
  //do something when none of the above conditions are met..
}
```

FYI... $(this) will reference the element you are providing the listener for inside the handler..in this case $('#efm select[name="type"]') ... will save you some typing :)

Comment: TypeError: $(...) is null

Is the result from the above, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to alert the value of the select.

alert($('#efm select[name="type"]').val()); 
//you can also use $(this).val() there this will reduce the code size

and keep the other else part blank.

```
$('#efm select[name="type"]').change(function () {
  alert($(this).val());
  alert('is equal= '+$(this).val() == '123');

  if ($(this).val() == '123') {
    $('#first_name').hide();
  } else {
   alert('else part');
  }
});
```